# Can't resolve 'http' "in react"

Tags: reactjs

I downloaded the project from GitHub and then installed the npm install package.
Then I opened the project but it gives me this error

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDYuX.png)

Comment: The message you've pasted actually contains the steps required to fix the issue. You should try if they help.

Comment: If that project uses `http` which most likely means it is targeting node and not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways for understand this error. First in the terminal rode a comand 'npm fund fix', reference link: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-fund. Second search this module in the package.json and remove, after remove nodemodules folder and package.lock, and install the Project again. Don't forget the verify if this a problem the version compatibility.